# Cannot find symbol - variable calorias

Tags: java, lógica

Porque deste erro se eu estou definindo as calorias nos `ifs`?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Alimentos {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nDigite o Alimento (Vegetariano, Peixe, Frango ou Carne): ");
        String alimento = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nDigite a Bebida (Chá, Refri Diet, Suco de melancia ou Suco de Laranja): ");
        String bebida = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nDigite a Sobremesa (Abacaxi, Sorvete, Sorvete Diet ou Mousse): ");
        String sobremesa = in.nextLine();
        int calorias = 350;
        int caloriasbebida = 100;
        int caloriassobremesa = 200;
    if(alimento.toLowerCase().equals("vegetariano")){
        int calorias = 180;
    } else if(alimento.toLowerCase().equals("peixe")){
        int calorias = 230;
    } else if(alimento.toLowerCase().equals("frango")){
        int calorias = 250;
    }

    if(bebida.toLowerCase().equals("chá")){
        int caloriasbebida = 20;
    } else if(bebida.toLowerCase().equals("refri diet")){
        int caloriasbebida = 65;
    } else if(bebida.toLowerCase().equals("suco de melancia")){
        int caloriasbebida = 70;
    }

    if(sobremesa.toLowerCase().equals("abacaxi")){
        int caloriassobremesa = 75;
    } else if(sobremesa.toLowerCase().equals("sorvete")){
        int caloriassobremesa = 170;
    } else if(sobremesa.toLowerCase().equals("sorvete diet")){
        int caloriassobremesa = 110;
    }
    int resultado = calorias+caloriasbebida+caloriassobremesa;
    System.out.println("Total de Calorias da Refeição: " +resultado);
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está declarando as variáveis dentro do `if` então elas só existem dentro dele, quando sai, elas não existem mais. Você precisa aprender sobre [escopo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escopo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) (isto dá uma introdução mas para aprender mesmo seria bom acompanhar todos os conceitos em um bom livro).

Quando uma variável é declarada dentro de um escopo, ela deixa de existir quando sai deste escopo. Sempre que existe um bloco (em geral delimitado por chaves `{ }`) você está criando um novo escopo. Um escopo interno a outro escopo "herda" as variáveis no escopo anterior.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Alimento {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nDigite o Alimento (Vegetariano, Peixe, Frango ou Carne): ");
        String alimento = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nDigite a Bebida (Chá, Refri Diet, Suco de melancia ou Suco de Laranja): ");
        String bebida = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nDigite a Sobremesa (Abacaxi, Sorvete, Sorvete Diet ou Mousse): ");
        String sobremesa = in.nextLine();
        int calorias = 350;
        int caloriasbebida = 100;
        int caloriassobremesa = 200;
        if (alimento.toLowerCase().equals("vegetariano")) calorias = 180;
        else if (alimento.toLowerCase().equals("peixe")) calorias = 230;
        else if (alimento.toLowerCase().equals("frango")) calorias = 250;
        if (bebida.toLowerCase().equals("chá")) caloriasbebida = 20;
        else if (bebida.toLowerCase().equals("refri diet")) caloriasbebida = 65;
        else if (bebida.toLowerCase().equals("suco de melancia")) caloriasbebida = 70;
        if (sobremesa.toLowerCase().equals("abacaxi")) caloriassobremesa = 75;
        else if (sobremesa.toLowerCase().equals("sorvete")) caloriassobremesa = 170;
        else if (sobremesa.toLowerCase().equals("sorvete diet")) caloriassobremesa = 110;
        int resultado = calorias + caloriasbebida + caloriassobremesa;
        System.out.println("Total de Calorias da Refeição: " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vj87lg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/abnbkgcg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/VariableScope2.java).

Este código ainda tem um problema se o usuário não digitar nada.

Otimizei seu código original da pergunta inicializando a variável `calorias` com 350, para matar todo `else`.

Aproveito para dizer que seria bom organizar o código de forma mais padronizada. Isto ajuda entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Eu tentei validar as variaveis como 0 antes do if tambem! (lembrei dessa aula um pouco depois de postar rsrs) porem ao inves de ele trocar o valor dentro dos `ifs` ele retorna este erro: `variable calories is already defined in method main` ele nao está trocando o valor :/

Comment: Porque você tentou declarar ela várias vezes. Você só pode declarar uma variável uma vez dentro do escopo. E o escopo é aninhado. Ou seja, os escopos mais internos herdam tudo que já foi declarado no escopo mais externo, então o que for tentando declarado dentro do `if` não pode ser igual ao que já foi declarado fora dele.

Comment: Mas eu estou tentando declarar valores diferentes :/ editei a pergunta com o código que eu estou tentando compilar e obtendo o erro acima. Eu comecei com 350 como  voce deu a dica e estou tentando mudar para valores diferentes deste

Comment: Ja adicionei o programa inteiro para voce entender a ideia rsrs

Comment: @Guilherme evite mudar a pergunta depois de postada a não ser que seja para esclarecer mais, você poderia invalidar as respostas. Por isso sempre é bom pensar bem se já postou tudo o que precisava na primeira vez. Eu postei a versão nova. O problema é o mesmo, você não pode declara variáveis dentro do `if` que já foram declarada fora dele. Você pode usar as variáveis declaradas fora dele, afinal um escopo interno herda o que existe no escopo externo, mas não pode declarar de novo porque ela já está declarada. Para resolver basta retirar a declaração e só usá-las. Estude sobre escopo.

Comment: Entendi vacilo meu :# Muito obrigado pelo suporte!